# Nginx http_status_module statistics

Tags: nginx

I am interested in the statistics provided by the http_status_module
particularly the statistics in the upstream section.

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_status_module.html

However, they are only available as part of the commercial license. Is there an open source version of this module.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of project that come close to it a new one:

https://github.com/vozlt/nginx-module-vts

And in senginx.org you can try to compile nginx with that module (ngx_http_statistics) with requires to patch some core files of nginx

Another alternative depending on what kind of stats you need would be to use lua and there are several project on this on github to give you a head start.
here is one i used as a base for my stat.

https://github.com/yandex-sysmon/nginx-lua-stats

Answer (score 0):

You can try to download and compile the source

http://trac.nginx.org/nginx/browser/nginx/src/http/modules/ngx_http_status_module.c?rev=b52b6c3bb2d1d6f809afbacbc2e2a1b090a68b40

I actually don't know if the open source version of NGinx support this.  Maybe could have some dependencies that you'll need to compile or adapt.

Regards

Comment: The source code you linked is from 8 years ago and the commercial version was released 1 year ago, so I doubt this is what he is looking for.  Having said that, the open source version has a much simpler version of the status page that you can build using --with-http_stub_status_module.